# Do azure-functions support deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

azure-functions are a special type of App Service on Azure. The other main Azure App Services (web & api) support multiple deployment slots on a sufficient App Service Plan (S1 and up). It seems likely that this is also an option for azure-functions, but I can not find the configuration area. Am I just not finding it or is this functionally not available for azure-functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 5/13/2017**: slots are now supported as a Preview feature.

**Original answer:**

Deployment slots are not supported at this time in Azure Functions. However, they will be supported going forward. Slots raise some interesting issues, and we want to make sure we tackle them before enabling this.

Comment: I guess in the mean time, a lot of the same functionality can be emulated by either, using the webjobs-script-sdk in a traditional continuous webjob, or by setting up multiple azure-function apps to treat a slots.

Comment: is there any time frame on the roadmap to have the slots functionality any time soon?

Comment: It is something that will happen, but we do not have a precise ETA to share at this time. I expect it's less than 4 months away.

Comment: Slots are now available for Functions. Ofcourse, there are still in 'Preview'

Comment: @Prawin indeed. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Any idea when this will go out of preview, seeing how it's been 2 days under a year since this answer was updated?

Comment: @Sam sorry, this is still not finalized.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks David. I suppose in the meantime a function proxy is the way to do this?